# Removing the selections on selectOneListbox / selectManyMenu on a button click in Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

So i have designed a simple form having selectOneListbox / selectManyMenu elements which I am using to generate a piece of text based upon the user selections.

It's working fine. Now what I want is when the user clicks 'clear' button, the selections should be undone and the page should come back to the initial state(no selections).

How can I achieve this ?

xhtml

```
        <h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="6" style="margin-bottom:10px;" cellpadding="5" columnClasses="label, value">
    <p:panel>
    <h6 style="width:10.4em;background-color:#ACBECE;">Comment  Type</h6>
    <!-- comment type -->
    <p:selectOneListbox id="basic1" value="#{decisionTreeBean.option1}" style=" font-size: 12px;background-color:silver;width:12em; height:10em; border-style:solid !important;border-width:0.5px !important; border-color:grey !important;">
         <f:selectItems value="#{decisionTreeBean.commentType}" var="X" itemLabel="#{X}" itemValue="#{X}" />
    </p:selectOneListbox>
    </p:panel>
<p:panel>
        <h6 style="width:10.4em;background-color:#ACBECE;">MTCN</h6>
        <p:selectManyMenu id="advanced1" value="#{decisionTreeBean.option2}" showCheckbox="true" style="font-size: 12px;background-color:silver;width:12em; height:10em; border-style:solid !important;border-width:0.5px !important; border-color:grey !important;">
            <f:selectItems value="#{decisionTreeBean.mtcns}" var="X" itemLabel="#{X}" itemValue="#{X}" />                  
        </p:selectManyMenu>
        </p:panel>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <!-- Text Area -->
    <p:inputTextarea  id="decisionNotes" readonly="#{facesContext.renderResponse}" value="#{decisionTreeBean.decisionNotes}" styleClass="dispostionInputTextArea" autoResize="true">
    </p:inputTextarea>
    <br/>
    <p:commandButton  id="generateBtn" value="Generate Text" action="#{decisionTreeBean.generateText}" update=":#{p:component('decisionNotes')}">
    </p:commandButton>

    <p:commandButton  id="clearBtn" value="Clear" action="#{decisionTreeBean.clearText}" update=":#{p:component('decisionNotes')}">
    </p:commandButton>
    <p:ajaxStatus onstart="PF('statusDialog').show()"
            onsuccess="PF('statusDialog').hide()" />
        <p:dialog widgetVar="statusDialog" modal="true" draggable="false"
            closable="false" resizable="false" showHeader="false">
            <p:graphicImage value="/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
        </p:dialog>

    </h:form>
```

In my bean, I have a clear method which clears the content of the textarea. I want this button to undo the selections as well as part of the ajax call.

```
public void clearText() {
        this.decisionNotes=" ";
    }
```

[image: What it looks like]

(for brevity I have included just 2 columns here in xhtml. There are in total 5 separate selection columns with same functionality)

Comment: how about update the component from clear button?

Comment: Yes. That worked. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply reset the values of the Menu/Box in the bean method too:

```
public void clearText() {
    this.decisionNotes=" ";
    this.option1 = null;
    //and so on...
}
```

Then you just need to update the components in the update attribute of your button. But I'd update the whole form instead of each component if you want to refresh nearly each component in the form. So just use `update="@form"`:

Note: The default process value of p:commandButton is @form. So your clear button will process the whole form on every click altough it doesn't need to. I'd set it to `process="@this"`, so it will just perform it's action.

Comment: Can you also tell me how I can have rows inside of my columns ?  Something like  all items in my selectOneListbox / selectManyMenu should be seperated by horizontal line.

Comment: That should be possible using CSS, but im not an CSS expert.